# NSTokenField value changed notification

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac, nstokenfield

while typing inside `NSTokenField`  I show suggestions for this value, with  `GetCompletionStrings` from `NSTokenFieldDelegate`

```
public override string [] GetCompletionStrings (NSTokenField tokenField, string substring, nint tokenIndex, nint selectedIndex)
        {
            //return my values
        }
```

but if I will completely remove all symboled from NSTokenFiled this event won't be fired.

I need to catch notification when `NSTokenFiled string value` will changed or cleared or updated, without click enter button.

I use custom nstoken field `TokenField : NSTokenField` inside it I had override DidEndEditing, like this :

```
public override void DidEndEditing (NSNotification notification)
        {
            if (EditingFinished != null) {
                EditingFinished (null, null);
            }
            base.DidEndEditing (notification);
        }
```

this is only called after enter clicked , isn't fired on text change...

I also tried to handle change event of my view in view controller, but it is not called

```
TagsSearchField.EditingFinished += OnTagFilterSet;
        TagsSearchField.Delegate = new TagFieldDelegate ();
        TagsSearchField.Changed += (o, e) => {
        //debug
        };
```

Comment: I have also tried to handle event in constructor: 
[Export ("initWithCoder:")]
  public TokenField (NSCoder coder) : base (coder)
  {
   this.Changed += (o, e) => {
    //debug
   };
  }
but still no result

Answer (score 1):

I set Action  'Sent On End Editing ' to Token Field, in xib file and it works now .

After this Change event is called

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Changed` event to capture all editing changes with the `NSTokenField`; including clear, clipboard cuts, etc..

```
tokenField = new NSTokenField(new CGRect(100, 100, 300, 40));
tokenField.Delegate = this;
tokenField.Changed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"changed: {tokenField.StringValue}");
    var tokenArray = tokenField.ObjectValue as NSArray;
    for (nuint i = 0; i < tokenArray.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tokenArray.GetItem<NSString>(i));
    }
};
View.AddSubview(tokenField);
```

Comment: I have updated question, unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: I set Action  'Sent On End Editing ', in xib file and it works now .

Comment: GetCompletionStrings is not called if change is handled  :/